# I need a single regex to check number comma and number

Tags: regex

I need a regX which can match like  **123,123** only. My regX is

```
var regX = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])*$/;
```

but its currently matching **123,123** and **123,** as well

Valid case: **123,123 or 123,000** or 000,000
Invalid case: **123.123** or 123?123 or '123'.'123'

Comment: Could you put more examples of strings to match and not to match? Also, is this javascript?

Comment: What is the point of `\d*[0-9]`?

Comment: Provide more samples (for example, is `123,000` correct)

Comment: Is `1,234,567` valid or not?

Comment: @M42 I need two regX, correct valid case for first **85345** or **85345,12345** or **85345,12345,12345** and valid case for second **3004** or **3004,2123**. consider this as a example. digits are not fixed and digits can be multiple comma separators.

Answer (score 2):

you should use this regex = `\d+(,\d+)+`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the `{x,y}` quantifier.  I matches at least X of the item, and at most Y.  If you leave one out, it has no limit in that direction.  If you just have one number, with no comma it matches exactly that amount.

Exactly three digits:

```
(\d{3}),(\d{3})
```

Three or more

```
(\d{3,}),(\d{3,})
```

Between 2 and 7 digits:

```
(\d{2,7}),(\d{2,7})
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're actually trying to match a number with thousand separators.

Try this: `/\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*/`

Comment: You probably won't to use the `^` and `$` as this will match partial numbers in floating point numbers like `123.54`.

Comment: here digits are fixed between 1,3 can we make it more generic.

Comment: @s.singh Why do you want "more generic"? When you write a number separated by commas, there will never be anything other than 1-3 digits before the first comma, otherwise it's not a properly formatted number.

Comment: @Kolink--if I test it by putting **123,123,asdf** its still matching and numbers are not fixed upto 3 digits.

Comment: Then you need to read Sniffer's comment and put `^` and `$` in your regex: `/^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$/`

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are positive integers you can use:  \d+,\d+
If you want floating point numbers as well:   (\d|.)+,(\d|.)+
although this will also match malformed numbers with multiple or misplaced decimal points including .,. etc.